# Undefined logic goes wrong

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using hp on demand API, it will return an object as in this form for a postive query.

```
var obj = {
  "positive": [
    {
      "sentiment": "love",
      "topic": null,
      "score": 0.8053406931054015,
      "original_text": "I love you",
      "original_length": 10,
      "normalized_text": "I love you",
      "normalized_length": 10
    }
  ],
  "negative": [],
  "aggregate": {
    "sentiment": "positive",
    "score": 0.8053406931054015
  }
}
```

And it will return object like this for negative query

```
{
  "positive": [],
  "negative": [
    {
      "sentiment": "hate",
      "topic": null,
      "score": -0.8748623139495181,
      "original_text": "I hate you",
      "original_length": 10,
      "normalized_text": "I hate you",
      "normalized_length": 10
    }
  ],
  "aggregate": {
    "sentiment": "negative",
    "score": -0.8748623139495181
  }
}
```

And I am trying to assign property normalized_text to text, but there seems to be a logical error using undefined. Here is my code

```
var arr = ["I hate you", "I love you", "I miss you"];

var emotions = [];

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){

//console.log(arr[i]);
    $.ajax({

  url: "https://api.idolondemand.com/1/api/sync/analyzesentiment/v1?text="+arr[i]+"&apikey=e3b26b74-bla"

  })
  .done(function( data ) {
    var obj = data;
    //emotions.push(obj.aggregate.sentiment);
    var text;
    if(typeof obj.positive[0].normalized_text === "undefined"){
        text = obj.negative[0].normalized_text;
    }else{
    text = obj.positive[0].normalized_text;
    }

    console.log(text);   
    console.log(obj.aggregate.sentiment);

  });

}
```

my error is `cannot read normalized_text of undefined`

Comment: `obj.positive[0]` is undefined already, resulting in a resolving attempt for `undefined.normalized_text`, which is an error, since `undefined` is not an object.

Comment: You would probably have to parse the JSON data before referring to its object literals.

Comment: Can you shrink the example?

Comment: Unfortunately no @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access an object which might be undefined at times i.e, negative. It is better to check whether the negative is null or not before trying to access it.

```js
if (typeof obj.positive[0] !== "undefined") {
  text = obj.positive[0].normalized_text;
} else if (typeof obj.negative[0] !== "undefined") {
  text = obj.negative[0].normalized_text;
}
```